# Doesn't the return exit the loop and return true as the last statement in this code?

Tags: java, return

Doesn't the `return` exit the loop and return `true` as the last statement in this code? If so, doesn't it always return true?

```
    private boolean isWord(String token) { 
       for (int i = 0; i < token.length(); i++) {
         char ch = toekn.charAt(i);
         if (!Character.isLetter(ch)) return false;
       }
       return true;
    }
```

Comment: Not if the `if` is false. Go over the method with debug and watch what happens.

Comment: Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, on the first encounter of a non-letter character the execution of the code will let the function return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return x` keyword returns the value `x` from the currently executing ***function***.  That's how it works.

The only circumstances where `x` will not *necessarily* be returned by `return x` is if the `return x` statement is inside a `try { ... }` block, which is followed by a `finally` block, and the `finally` block contains a `return y` statement.

If you wanted to exit the current loop you would have used `break` instead of `return`.

Comment: No matter how many statements in the function, does it always return `x` from the executing function?

Comment: I amended my answer to indicate the only situation under which `x` will not be necessarily returned by `return x`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two returns, one inside the loop. This one returns false `if(!Character.isLetter(ch))` (if ch isn't a letter). When the loop finishes it reaches the `return true`.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` keyword stops execution within the enclosing function, and returns the value attached to it, in this case, `return true`.

However, if the `if` condition is satisfied, `return false` exits the function, and returns the boolean value `false` to the calling code.

Finally, `return true` will never be reached until the `for-loop` completes its iteration, and the `if` condition inside the `for loop` is not executed.

I hope this explains your question succinctly.